# How to use/create a real time clock to use with specialized?

Tags: integrated-circuit, timing, timing-analysis

I want an accurate clock that will output a square wave that operates at 1 Hz. I need it to connect to a chain of binary counters. When the right binary number has been achieved the outputs will trigger AND logic gates to advances the count on the display. This would happen once every 86400 seconds (1 Day).

I don't know if this means using an RTC but the ones I have researched are only connected to microcontrollers.

I have tried using a 555 in astable mode but did not receive accurate results (I did not use a crystal).

If anyone knows any way to achieve this, please let me know.

Thank you.

Comment: No one is going to do this without an MCU unless there's a single fixed function IC which exactly matches their need.  You haven't specified your need, and shopping questions are off topic anyway so this will probably end up an exercise in low power mcu design

Comment: Most people would use a 32.678kHz quartz clock crystal, then keep dividing it by two to get 1.0Hz.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[CD4060 IC binary counter + Osc](http://www.ti.com/general/docs/suppproductinfo.tsp?distId=10&gotoUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ti.com%2Flit%2Fgpn%2Fcd4060b)  follow Xtal Osc design
Use Q15 = divide by 2^15= 32,768 = 1 Hz

Xtal 32,768 kHz   + discrete RC parts  or [MEMS OSC XO 32.7680KHZ CMOS SMD](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/crystals-oscillators-resonators/oscillators/172?k=32768&k=&pkeyword=32768&sv=0&pv253=1658&pv253=2011&pv253=2085&pv253=2647&sf=1&FV=-8%7C172%2C7%7C3&quantity=&ColumnSort=0&page=1&stock=1&pageSize=25)
more  CD4060/4040's and gates to reset after output = 86,400 s
1 0101 0001 1000 0000 = 86,400

3V or 3.6V Li Ion

Comment: Thanks this worked

Comment: I forgot to mention CD4060 only goes up to Q14 , but you figured it. Out

Comment: yes I just used another another ripple counter to divide the frequency